# AndroidStudio не видит девайсы из Genymotion

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

Скачал Genymotion, тк стандартный эмулятор Android studio очень медленный. Скачал плагин для AS, поменял ADB в настройках Genymotion так как сказали в интернете. В первый раз, сразу после установки плагина я смог запустить модуль в AS используя устройство из geny. Но после закрытия обоих приложений и попытки повторного запуска AS просто не предлагает девайс из geny, хотя в плагине пишет что устройство включено. Перепробывал все найденные варианты: поставил запуск от имени администратора, запускал сначала AS потом geny и наоборот, но устройства снова так и не появились.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось частично "победить" данную проблему на Linux.

Debian 4.9.0-8-amd64 + Android Studio 3.3.2 + Genymotion 3.0.1 (предполагается, что все необходимое установлено)

Запускаем Android Studio (далее AS) -> Genymotion Device Manager (далее GDM) -> Выбираем предустановленный образ Android устройства и жмем Start. После того, как Genymotion запустил виртуальный девайс, запоминаем его IP (например, 192.168.56.101), закрываем GDM и открываем терминал AS. Здесь необходимо перезапустить adb-server.

Останавливаем сервер

```
adb kill-server
```

Запускаем снова

```
adb start-server
```

Соединяемся с устройством

```
adb connect 192.168.56.101:5555
```

Если забыли IP, его можно посмотреть снова открыв GDM.
В терминале должна появиться надпись "connected to 192.168.56.101:5555"
Запускаем приложение (Shift+F10) и в разделе Connected Devices окна Select Deployment Target видим наше устройство. Например, Genymotion Google Nexus 5X (Android 8.0.0, API 26)

**Если не установлен adb**, в терминале пишем

```
sudo apt install adb
```

Проверяем версию adb

```
/usr/bin/adb version
```

Сверяем с версией, которая лежит в SDK

```
/путь_к_папке_со_студией/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb version
```

Если версия /usr/bin/adb ниже той, что находится в /Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb, удаляем adb и создаем ссылку на более новую

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo rm /usr/bin/adb
sudo ln -s /путь_к_папке_со_студией/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb  /usr/bin/adb
sudo adb start-server
```

Надеюсь, кому-то помог